# How do I Bind a TemplateColumn Visibility to selectedValue of other columnin WPF DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding, datagrid

I have a little problem with my datagrid. I searched on stackoverflow, but could not find answer that can resolve my case.

I have a window with a DataGrid. The window datacontext is bound to ViewModel.
On my datagrid, I have mutliple column, but now, what matters, there are three column :
the first one is a datatemplate column that contains a ComboBox with multiples entries, the second is a datatemplate column with a TextBox and the third one is a datatatemplate column with another combobox.

Depending of the choice in the first column ComboBox, I want to hide/make visible the second and the third, depending of the type (they cannot be both visible at same time).

So I've made a property in my ViewModel

```
  public Visibility MetierListVisibility
    {
        get
        {
            return _metierListVisibility;
        }
        set
        {
            _metierListVisibility = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged();
        }
    }
```

And I bind this property to my DataColumn in XAML :

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Valeur"  Width="2*" x:Name="cln_value"
                                    Visibility="{Binding Data.MetierListVisibility, Source={StaticResource proxy}, Converter={StaticResource InverseVisibilityConverter}}">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Value, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Grid>
                            <TextBox Text="{Binding Value, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}" Initialized="TextBox_Initialized" x:Name="tb_content" MouseLeftButtonUp="tb_content_MouseDown" />
                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Valeur"  Width="2*" x:Name="cln_value_metier" 
                                    Visibility="{Binding Data.MetierListVisibility, Source={StaticResource proxy}}" >
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Value, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True, Converter={StaticResource MetierConvertor}}" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Grid>
                            <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}, Path=DataContext.Metiers}" 
                                      DisplayMemberPath="Value" SelectedValuePath="Key" SelectedValue="{Binding Value}" />
                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Here's XAML for my first column :

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Champ" x:Name="LineField" Width="1.5*">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Field , ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ComboBox Name="cb_Fields" ItemsSource="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}, Path=DataContext.ListFields}"
                                  SelectedItem="{Binding Field}" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

I don't know how to proceed to refresh my columns when change on first column ?
The data selected in my first column is present in my datasource, so I try this :

```
private void cb_Fields_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        (gd_filterCriterion as DataGrid).GetBindingExpression(DataGrid.SelectedItemProperty).UpdateSource();
    }
```

Because on my grid, SelectedItem is linked to this :

```
 public Criterion SelectedCriterion
    {
        get
        {
            return _selectedCriterion;
        }
        set
        {
            _selectedCriterion = value;
            MetierListVisibility = (value != null && value.Field == "Métier" ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Hidden);
            RaisePropertyChanged();
            RaisePropertyChanged("MetierListVisibility");
        }
    }
```

Thanks for help !

Comment: are you sure grid is right control for such req ? I mean what If first column's values are different in 2 rows ?

Comment: You're right, I haven't think of that point ... So I move my two controls in the same column and apply my visibility member to control ! Thanks

Comment: :) let us know if u stuck!